# How to configure Tarui app to read configuration

Tags: typescript, rust, tauri

I want to store a Tauri app's user configuration in an external file.
The TypeScript front end does this:

```js
import {appConfigDir} from "tauri-apps/api/path";
...
await fetch(`${await appConfigDir()}symbol-sets.json`) {
    ...
}
```

By logging to the console, I can see that it is trying to fetch from `C:\Users\padeso\AppData\Roaming\padeso-svg-symbol-tool\symbol-sets.json`

In `tauri.conf.json`, I added

```json
"tauri": {
      "fs": {
        "readFile": true,
        "scope": ["$APPCONFIG/*"],
      },
```

I don't know how to confirm how Tauri is interpreting `"$APPCONFIG/*"`, but according to my reading of the documentation, I would expect it to resolve to the same location as the code.
Nevertheless, it errors:

```js
Not allowed to load local resource:
file:///C:/Users/padeso/AppData/Roaming/padeso-svg-symbol-tool/symbol-sets.json
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: the file:// url doesn't (really) exist in tauri, try the asset protocol via https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/tauri/#convertfilesrc instead (make sure to configure the assetScope too, it does not use the fs scope)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `readTextFile` API call:

```js
import { readTextFile, BaseDirectory } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';
// Read the text file in the `$APPCONFIG/symbol-sets.conf` path
const contents = await readTextFile('symbol-sets.conf', { dir: BaseDirectory.AppConfig });
const symbolSets = JSON.parse(contents);
console.log(symbolSets);
```

Comment: That works. I didn't think it would because I assumed "BaseDirectory" would be relative to the app. For what it's worth, I also got fetch working, using @FabianLars suggestion, i.e. treating the configuration file as an "asset" rather than as a file.

Comment: Glad to hear it! For production we usually end up having a custom command that does reading processing in rust, and controls what files can be accessed with more granularity. It's on the dev, rather than Tauri, but it worked better for us for apps we deploy to the customers.

Answer (score 0):

While @DeveloperMindset.com's approach works well, I was also able to get this
working using @FabianLars suggestion of treating the external files as assets instead
of as files. Here are the details, in case they are useful to someone else.

Instead of setting the file system allow list in `tauri.conf.json`, set the protocol allow list:

```json
"tauri": {
    "protocol": {
        "asset": true,
        "assetScope": ["$APPCONFIG/*]
    }
}
```

Then in the frontend, get the URL of the file/asset, like so:

```js
import {appConfigDir, join} from "@tauri-apps/api/path";
import {convertFileSrc} from "@tauri-apps/api/tauri";
...
const appConfigDirPath = await appConfigDir();
const configFilePath = await join(appConfigDirPath, 'symbol-sets.json');
const configUrl = convertFileSrc(configFilePath);

await fetch(configUrl, {mode: 'cors'}) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you must specify CORS. The URL in this case (on my system) is `https://asset.localhost/C%3A%5CUsers%5Cpadeso%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5Cpadeso-svg-symbol-tool%5Csymbol-sets.json`